# AzCopy blob download throwing errors on local machine

Tags: azure

I am running the following command while learning how to use AzCopy.

```
azcopy /Source:https://storeaccountname.blob.core.windows.net/container /Dest:C:\container\ /SourceKey:Key /Pattern:"tdx" /S /V
```

Some files are downloaded by most files result in an error like the following. I have no idea why this happening and wondered if somebody has encountered this and knows the cause and the fix.

```
[2016/05/31 21:27:13][ERROR] tdx/logs/site-visit/archive/1463557944558/visit-1463557420000: Failed to open file C:\container\tdx\logs\site-visit\archive\1463557944558\visit-1463557420000: Access to the path 'C:\container\tdx\logs\site-visit\archive\1463557944558\visit-1463557420000' is denied..
```

My ultimate goal was to create backups of the blobs in a container of one storage account to the container of another storage account. So I am starting out with basics which seem to fail.

Here is a list of folder names from an example path pulled from Azure Portal:

```
storeaccountname > Blob service > container > app-logs > hdfs > logs

application_1461803569410_0008
application_1461803569410_0009
application_1461803569410_0010
application_1461803569410_0011
application_1461803569410_0025
application_1461803569410_0027
application_1461803569410_0029
application_1461803569410_0031
application_1461803569410_0033
application_1461803569410_0035
application_1461803569410_0037
application_1461803569410_0039
application_1461803569410_0041
application_1461803569410_0043
application_1461803569410_0045
```

There is an error in the log for each one of these folders that looks like this:

```
[2016/05/31 21:29:18.830-05:00][VERBOSE] Transfer FAILED: app-logs/hdfs/logs/application_1461803569410_0008 => app-logs\hdfs\logs\application_1461803569410_0008.
[2016/05/31 21:29:18.834-05:00][ERROR] app-logs/hdfs/logs/application_1461803569410_0008: Failed to open file C:\container\app-logs\hdfs\logs\application_1461803569410_0008: Access to the path 'C:\container\app-logs\hdfs\logs\application_1461803569410_0008' is denied..
```

The folder application_1461803569410_0008 contains two files. Those two files were successfully downloaded. From the logs:

```
[2016/05/31 21:29:19.041-05:00][VERBOSE] Finished transfer: app-logs/hdfs/logs/application_1461803569410_0008/10.2.0.5_30050 => app-logs\hdfs\logs\application_1461803569410_0008\10.2.0.5_30050
[2016/05/31 21:29:19.084-05:00][VERBOSE] Finished transfer: app-logs/hdfs/logs/application_1461803569410_0008/10.2.0.4_30050 => app-logs\hdfs\logs\application_1461803569410_0008\10.2.0.4_30050
```

So it appears that the problem is related to copying folders, which themselves are blobs but I can't be certain yet.

Comment: Is there anything in particular about the files which are failing? May be their names are containing some unallowed characters. Also, if your intention is backing up a container to another storage account, why are you downloading the files first on the local computer? You can simply use AzCopy to copy from one container to another.

Comment: @GauravMantri There is nothing in particular about the files failing. As I mentioned in the post I am learning how to use AzCopy so first step is to determine if I can download a blob and then upload a blob, and then copy a blob, etc. Well I should be able to simply download as well but that is not working. Your point is?

Comment: Regarding downloading/uploading just to do backup, what I am trying to say is that Azure Supports async blob copy across storage account that runs server side so you don't have to do download the blob first on your local computer and reupload it. You can delegate that task to Azure IMHO. Regarding failed files, can you give an example name of the file that is actually failing? Since the failure is because of some IO error (Access Denied), I am guessing something funky going on with the file path & names.

Comment: @GauravMantri I already know the capability to copy from one storage account to another is possible server side. Can you appreciate that I simply learning how the tool works through practice? I have updated the error in my post with an actual path.

Comment: I understand it now. Apologies if I offended you. My intention was not that. I simply assumed that you did not know about async copy. My bad! Coming back to problem at hand, can you tell me if the files that are failing are without any extension?

Comment: @GauravMantri I appreciate that you are trying to help. I am more frustrated with Azure then anything. It's a constant battle to get things working. I have updated my post with more information from the logs. It may be related to folders only.

Comment: I tried the exactly same path, same file (which without extension) with yours and it works on my side.

Comment: @Derek The file transferred fine by the folder caused the error. What is the path you used?

Comment: Same as yours. I created a file names **visit-1463557420000** (without extension) and uploaded it to the container with the path **tdx/logs/site-visit/archive/1463557944558**.  And the Azcopy download command works like a charm.

Comment: @Derek That is actually a folder. If you look at my example further down in the post I discovered that the errors only occur for folders. However, the files in those folders are downloaded.

Comment: Refer to https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazurestorage/2012/12/03/azcopy-uploadingdownloading-files-for-windows-azure-blobs/. Scroll down to the bottom, see the last bullet of **Known Issues**.  The only possible reason I've found. Get back to me after you check.

Answer (score 1):

There are several known issues when using AzCopy, such as the below which will cause error,

- If there are two blobs named “a” and “a/b” under a storage container, copying the blobs under that container with /S will fail. Windows will not allow the creation of folder name “a” and file name “a” under the same folder.

Refer to https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazurestorage/2012/12/03/azcopy-uploadingdownloading-files-for-windows-azure-blobs/. Scroll down to the bottom, see details of Known Issues.

In my container **con2**, there are a **folder** named abc.pdf and also a **file** abc.pdf, when executing Azcopy download command with /S, it will prompt a error message.

[image]

[image]

Please check your container whether there are folders with the same name as a file.

Comment: I missed that known issue you highlighted. I do believe that is the problem. However, I do not have duplicate files as you indicated rather I have duplicate folders everywhere. Every single folder has a blob with the same name associated with it. I confirmed in my AzCopy logs that only folders are throwing errors. That article is also over three years old. I assume those known issues would have been resolved by now. Obviously something is wrong. I wonder why there is a folder and blob with the same name. I did not do that.

Comment: To be accurate it's not an issue really, since Windows has some rules on storage itself. I can't figure out why there is folder and blob with the same name in your container, anyway, we found the root cause.

Comment: Same story for me though I am using the latest version of AzCopy. I am guessing it will not be "fixed" in the future releases.